# Sequelize returns _previousDataValues, _options, options, and all kinds of other junk

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js

If I run a simple query like the following, I get an object with all this extra junk ( _previousDataValues, _options, options, etc). How do I disable this meta data and return only the actual dataValues? I can't find anything in the spotty documentation.

```
models.Product.findAll({
  attributes: ["id", "name"]
})
```

Answer (score 6):

All this 'junk' is used by sequelize to do the fancy stuff that ORMs do: keep change of changed values etc. etc...

They will be removed automagically when you serialize the instances to JSON, or you might do so manually using `.get({ plain: true })` or `.toJSON()`

Comment: `.get({ plain: true })` is the correct answer. But it's worth noting that you should probably put off calling it for as long as possible: the "plain" version is not a model instance, and therefore does not provide any of the ORM sugar that attracted you to sequelize in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `{raw: true}` like this:

```
const users = await User.findAll({raw: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
models.Product.findAll({ 
    attributes: ["id", "name"] 
}).then(function(produts) {
     // only products here
})
```

Comment: Molda, thanks for your response but this still returns all the extra parameters (_previousDataValues, __options, etc).

Comment: Do you mean that the products objects have properties like _previousDataValues and __options. So it looks like products = [{id: 654,_previousDataValues: <whatever>},{id: 987,_previousDataValues: <whatever>}]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used ".toJSON()", and it worked.